# Two machines have the same "tree" but a different number of directories (under Properties)

Tags: properties, tree

I mirror a directory from server A to Server B nightly (the software doesn't matter in this case).

If I run a tree command on both servers, import those trees into Word and run a compare, there is no difference other than the header.

But if I right click the directory and select Properties, the source lists 55.735 directories and the destination lists 55,265 directories. Using DIR /S /ADH shows no hidden directories on the source. And I'm running this with no one on either server.

So I'm curious how could the trees be the same but the number of directories be different. I am going through each subdirectory, but obviously that is going to take a while.

Comment: The software used for the copy is actually of interest, as are the operating systems on both sides.

Comment: It's SyncBackPro -- but please don't get sidetracked by the software -- I'm just comparing two directory trees.

As noted below it's Windows server 2016 and 2019. Neither server has long names activated, but while 2019 can handle directory paths over 260 characters, 2016 gives errors. I had someone add about 188 directories that went over the limit.

That said: I've read Properties isn't really the best option for a directory count.

dir /a:d /s /b | find /c ":/" gives a different number and shows the path errors better.

Comment: Maybe you should enable long paths.

Comment: I wish, but I can't. Some pieces of software are not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Certain file systems and certain hosting protocols
Recognize specific types of files, and folders
(as well as of certain names/and length)
I favor iSCSI because it *emulates disks* more accurately across platforms.

EDIT: Im pretty sure... iSCSI emulates raw disk access... which means the client is always at fault for not seeing something.
I know NTFS+/SMBx lanman... blah, blah... depends on permissions.
thats why i say iSCSI.

Comment: These are sister devices. Same hardware specs. Both are Windows Server (2016 and 2019) . Their recognition capabilities should be the same.

Comment: You may wish to consider Beyond Compare (Scooter Software). It does have a trial, and options to compare all files including hidden.

Comment: Thanks John. I'll check it out.

Comment: So Beyond Compare agreed with tree.

Answer (score 0):

So it ends up the difference was caused by the way Windows Server 2016 and 2019 handle paths that are too long (with Long names turned off).

It was a good exercise because I also found 6000 hidden/system lock files left behind by Word files due to VPN disconnects.

Answer (score 0):

To get full compatibility for long paths, this feature should be enabled.

Enabling long paths does not affect software that doesn't use this feature.